# Reading special file using read.csv

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I have a file `.csv` format looking like this:

```
"Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4"
"1, ""Hello, world!"", 7, 5"
"4, ""Name"", 4, 3"
```

I need to read this file using `read.csv`. For `sep = ","` I get full `NA` dataframe. For `sep = "\t"` I get only one column parsed as one string. I tried using `quote = ""\"`, but it also doesn't work.
How can I ignore quotes and read my file correctly?
The expected result is:

```
Col1 Col2          Col3 Col4
1    Hello, world! 7    5
4    Name          4    3
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `myfile.csv` written reproducibly in the Note at the end, use `read.csv` twice.  The first `read.csv` will strip out the outer quotes and the second `read.csv` then reads what is left.

```
read.csv(text = read.csv("myfile.csv", header = FALSE)[[1]])
```

giving:

```
  Col1           Col2 Col3 Col4
1    1  Hello, world!    7    5
2    4           Name    4    3
```

### Note

```
Lines <- '"Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4"\n"1, ""Hello, world!"", 7, 5"\n"4, ""Name"", 4, 3"\n'
cat(Lines, file = "myfile.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

An option may be read with `readLines`, make changes with regex to replace the delimiter that are not between two letters to a different delimiter and read with `read.table`

```
df1 <- read.table(text = gsub("([a-z]),\\s*([a-z])(*SKIP)(*F)|,", ";", 
   gsub('"+', "", readLines("file1.csv")), perl = TRUE), sep=";", 
      strip.white = TRUE, header = TRUE)
```

-output

```
df1
#  Col1          Col2 Col3 Col4
#1    1 Hello, world!    7    5
#2    4          Name    4    3


 str(df1)
#'data.frame':  2 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ Col1: int  1 4
# $ Col2: chr  "Hello, world!" "Name"
# $ Col3: int  7 4
# $ Col4: int  5 3
```